# How can I setup a proxy connection in Solaris server?

Tags: proxy, solaris

I need to set up a proxy connection to access the internet. I am using Solaris server.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It would help if you say which program (or programs) you are using under Solaris to try to access Internet URLs since the way you specify proxies is different for, say, Gnome, wget, lynx, etc.

Answer (score 4):

set this as an environment variable:

```
> export http_proxy="http://domain_url\\username:password@proxy_url"
```

Comment: What if there is no username? Does this mean that any user can access the web via this proxy?